# Swing в jTable

Tags: jtable, swing

Возникла необходимость сделать таблицы и вставлять в них не только строки, но и компоненты swing. Просмотрела множество сайтов и так и не разобралась. Проект в NetBeans на java. Возможно кто-то сталкивался.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). (Но он сложный, предупреждаю.)